# Compiling Apk Server Side [corrupt]

Tags: php

i have problem, my website i have to unzip my APK file into folder,and the server usually compiles,for some reason now my apk which it compiles it corrupted, im newbie with this,i paid for the website coded,

maybe below is the problem?

You can browse through an apk, but when repackaging him you need to remove the meta-inf , copress, zip align and sign (which will re-add the meta-inf folder).

Comment: we do need some kind of source, or what you have tried so far

Comment: i actually think its down to unziping my apk? somthing to do with the meta? because the .apk works fine, but once in unzip it to upload to my server for it to compile it it hangs the app